# How to make my site use HTTPS for images or how to insert images as relative paths?

Tags: images, redirect, https, http

I recently added HTTPS to my domain and I have it so that http is redirected to https but my WordPress blog is still using http for it's images. I upload an image and it is using http. Is there something I can do to ensure that my images are using https when they are inserted into posts? I can check manually of course.

I found a similar post (not quite a duplicate) that suggested using relative paths. Is there some setting I can use to have WP insert images as relative paths? That way if I'm on http or https it will use the one I'm on.

Answer (score 2):

## Main Issue

As long as you are accessing the WordPress dashboard via HTTPS, new media items should be inserted into content using HTTPS in the associated media item URL. There is a bit more detail around that feature in this WordPress ticket: [wp_get_attachment_url returns https when it should not](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32112#comment:14).
That ticket describes how wp_get_attachment_url returns URL's that are protocol relative following an update in version 4.2. Following the related changes made editing any post and using wp_get_attachment_url to pull in URL's will use HTTPS.

Using relative paths for resources is another viable option, but since WordPress has various pieces of functionality that specify a full path, it seems easier to skip that option.

## How to Correct

To correct any old references to HTTP URL's, I would recommend using the various tools available to execute a "search and replace" across all posts/content in your site's database. You would essentially be searching for `http://domain.com/....` and replacing it with `https://domain.com/...`. My personal preference is interconnectit's serach and replace tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

However [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) is another solid option. Also you can go the plugin route with something like [Velvet Blues](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/).